# Объясните распиновку lan8720

Tags: arduino

Везде написано стандарт SI, SO, SCL и тд, а тут не понятно, при чем информации никакой не нашел

Comment: Самостоятельно вбить в поиск заголовок свокего вопроса не пробовали? Одна из множества ссылок, там и схема есть: https://www.terraelectronica.ru/news/4280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключить её можно, но в большинстве случаев оно того не стоит. Данный чип использует шину RMII, для этой шины есть библиотеки, например [эта](https://github.com/jmgiacalone/Arduino-libraries/blob/master/EMAC/rmii.h), но в целом работа с этой шиной на Arduino будет весьма непростым занятием. Надо понимать что Arduino хоть и хорошая но игрушка с очень узкими возможностями, если действительно хочется глубоко залезть в поделки на микроконтроллерах то я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону STM32.